# Cache implementation using RXJS in angular

Tags: angular, caching, rxjs, observable

I have a caching implementation on my angular application but it is not a robust one as I have not been able get certain aspects of the implementation fully functional .
These are the following end goals I wish to achieve .

1. Cache data using rxjs so that the data doesnt reload on every component initialization
2. Set a cache time so that the api response is updated periodically (if data is changed then it gets updated)
3. Invalidate cache immediately on specific user actions
4. Show loader everytime the data is refetched after cache invalidation. I do not want to define the loader state on each of my component files.

I have been able to achieve 1) and 3) but have little luck with 2) and 4)

Here goes a simplified version of the current implementation

```
//api.service.ts 
import {switchMap,BehaviorSubject,shareReplay} from 'rxjs'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

...other boiler plate
class APIService (){
  
 public dataSourceBS$ = new BehaviorSubject(undefined)
 public dataSource$ = dataSourceBS$.pipe(switchMap(() =>   this.http.get(someDataUrl)),shareReplay(1))
}


//myComponent.component.ts

class MyComponent{

constructor(inject api service){}

data$ = this.api.dataSource$ 

updateData(){
 this.dataSourceBS$.next()
}

}

//html file 

<div>
  {{data$ | async | json}}
</div>
<button (click)="updateData()">Invalidate cache</button>

}
```

The expectation is

1. to show a loader when cache is getting invalidated
2. Auto update data after a period regardless of whether the button is clicked or not

One possible solution for the loader is to use the tap operator but is there a way to modify the dataSource$ stream so that it emits a value of {loading:true} when the data is getting fetched

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you're looking for https://github.com/ngneat/cashew but that could be a quick win